# Hiberante Load properties inherit from super class, from a different table?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, infinispan, second-level-cache

I have following situation with hibernate.

Java Class Hierarchy

```
 Class A ; ( Table X) 

 Class B extends Class A :
 Class C extends Class A :

 Class D extends Class B :
 Class E extends Class C :
```

All these classes have hbm.xml files and only one table is there in database ( Table X).

In hbm files, hbm corresponding to `class A` is the root one and all other 
hbm fiels are  hbms of that root.

Now I want to cache, `class B` and `class D` using hibernate L2 cache.

Therefore I have added a new table ( table Y) to represent `class B` and `class D`.
Now hbm file relate to `class B` is made a root level hbm, and I can cache B and D entities.

But, in new table, I only want to add columns which are only relate to `class B` and `class D`. Since I do not want to break the
java class hierarchy, I want hibernate to load other properties which are inherited from supper class, when loading `class B` or `class D` entries. I think 
this can be done defining `class B`'s hbm as a `<joined-subclass>` but this way i'm losing caching ability.

Is there a way load properties inherit from super class, from a different table ? In this solution my caching requirement should be preserved.

I'm using infinispan as cache provider.

Comment: This seems like a Hibernate 2LC caching question, irrespective of the caching provider.